# Why am I getting two different results from the same javascript variable?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

The following is a mock up of a function I have been using in my functions.php file for my website.  It was working well until this last month (as far as I know).  The JavaScript is returning two different results for my concatenated string one being a string with the value of a php array index and the other being a string including the PHP array index in single quotes. I am not sure why this is happening now and how to fix it.

I have tried moving the entire string concatenation to php and that did not help.

```
function paypalpayment() {
    global $wpdb;
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $user_ID = $user->ID;
    $shortcode = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT MAX(ap.pending) AS pending, ap.book_datetime, ap.id, ap.hash FROM ea_appointments AS ap "
            ."INNER JOIN ea_users AS us ON ap.id_users_customer = us.id "
            ."WHERE us.wp_id ='".$user_ID."'");
    $hash = $shortcode->hash;

    $html = '';
    $html .= '<input style="width:250px" class="mb0 btn btn-lg btn-filled cfa-button" type="button" onclick="deletapt()" value="Delete Apt.">';
    $html .= '<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return"';
    $html .= '<script>
        var cancelurl = "https://www.myurl.com/' . $hash . '";
        function deletapt(){
            window.location = cancelurl;
        }
        $(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery("input[name=return]").val("https://www.myurl.com/payment-success/");
            jQuery("input[name=cancel_return]").val(cancelurl);
        });  
    </script>';
}
```

The problem is that now `cancelurl` is producing different results at different places:

In `function deletapt()` it is returning the correct result of:

```
"https://www.myurl.com/90241ba3ba27e246bcd9b17b76f0b463"
```

In `$(document).ready(function()` it is returning the odd result of:

```
"https://www.myurl.com/' .$shortcode->hash. '"
```

I need `$(document).ready(function()` to return

```
"https://www.myurl.com/90241ba3ba27e246bcd9b17b76f0b463"
```

How can I fix this.

Comment: With apologies, I think this must be observational error. The code above definitely won't produce `"https://www.myurl.com/90241ba3ba27e246bcd9b17b76f0b463"` in `deletapt` and `"https://www.myurl.com/' .$shortcode->hash. '"` in the `ready` callback. Some **other** code must be producing the `ready` callback where you see that problem.

Comment: Thanks.  This is new.  It was working for years.  I am wondering about a wordpress conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue was:

$(document).ready(function()

Needed to be

jQuery(document).ready(function()

I changed my theme and the new theme does not handle jQuery like the old theme (unfortunately).  I had to spell it out in my code after the switch and I missed this one.  All is well now.